# How to increase the loading speed of images on a web page which uses masonry js plugin

Tags: php, javascript, css, ajax, jquery-masonry

I am using [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) plugin and am trying to display a gallery like web page. 
Initially i am loading 10 images, when reached end of the page using ajax i am requesting next 10 images and then loading them .

The page seems to be aligned good **irrespective of their image heights**. But the thing is it loads very slow.

How can i optimize the speed so that it loads quickly.

Many thanks

Comment: It's the animation slow or the loading time of the pictures?

What are the sizes of the image files you are loading? Are you using thumbnails?

Comment: Actually i am rendering the data using an API. Thereby displaying the image in their respective div's from json response using a simple foreach. So the images are re-sized to 214px width. The background of the body is not an image. Just used a color attribute to fill.

Comment: And The response isn't contains thumbnails. It only gives a url to image or video

Comment: try http://www.smushit.com/ysmush.it/ to decrease image file size a bit without loss.

Comment: Can i decrease the size on the go. I mean i cant perfectly assume image properties. Because they are rendered from twitter,facebook,instagram.pinterst using postano api

Comment: @user1721135 sorry the solution you provided is not apt to my requirement !

Comment: Let me get this straight... your gallery uses an API which imports the pictures from postano. The API of theirs provides you with a parameter in order to select a size for the picture retrieved? It seems the images you are using to construct the gallery are too big for the use case.

Comment: @Ramarajudantuluri to find out which part of the process is actually taking the longest, make use of the Chrome Developer Tools, network panel. That will give you a better starting point, than guessing at what is taking a long time. https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/network

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [jQuery Lazy Load](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload).

> Lazy Load is a jQuery plugin written in JavaScript. It delays loading
>   of images in long web pages. Images outside of viewport (visible part
>   of web page) wont be loaded before user scrolls to them. This is
>   opposite of image preloading.
>
> Using Lazy Load on long web pages containing many large images makes
>   the page load faster. Browser will be in ready state after loading
>   visible images. In some cases it can also help to reduce server load.